# How do I modify a child object if it exists in array of objects using jq?

Tags: json, edit, jq

I'm trying to use jq to modify json data at various levels of an API request or response to enable support for API versioning.

Here's my (simplified) test JSON:

```
[
  {
    "note": null,
    "patient_id": 1,
    "phenotypes": [
      {
        "name": "Breast carcinoma",
        "observation": "present",
        "patient_id": 1,
        "person_id": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "Breast carcinoma",
        "observation": "present",
        "patient_id": 1,
        "person_id": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "note": null,
    "patient_id": 2
  },
  {
    "note": null,
    "patient_id": 3,
    "phenotypes": [
      {
        "name": "Breast carcinoma",
        "observation": "present",
        "patient_id": 3,
        "person_id": 3
      },
      {
        "name": "Breast carcinoma",
        "observation": "present",
        "patient_id": 3,
        "person_id": 3
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have an array of objects. Each object MAY have `"phenotypes"`, which I need to modify the content of, as well as removing `"note"` from the top level object.

Currently my jq is as follows:

```
[ map(del(.note, .age)) | .[] | select(.phenotypes != null) | .phenotypes |= map(del(.person_id)) ]
```

This almost works, but because of `select(.phenotypes != null)`, the second object in the array never makes it back after filtering.

I have also tried using if-then-else (end), however I couldn't make it not error, and I can't find any examples or documentation that suggests it can be used for further expression.

My expected output is the following:

```
[
  {
    "patient_id": 1,
    "phenotypes": [
      {
        "name": "Breast carcinoma",
        "observation": "present",
        "patient_id": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "Breast carcinoma",
        "observation": "present",
        "patient_id": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "patient_id": 2
  },
  {
    "patient_id": 3,
    "phenotypes": [
      {
        "name": "Breast carcinoma",
        "observation": "present",
        "patient_id": 3
      },
      {
        "name": "Breast carcinoma",
        "observation": "present",
        "patient_id": 3
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

`note` has been removed from root.
`person_id` has been removed from `phenotypes`.

Comment: I have included the expected output. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
map(del(.note, .age)) |
map( 
    if .phenotypes then 
        (.phenotypes |= map(del(.person_id)))
    else
        .
    end 
)
```

[Working example](https://jqterm.com/#!/e68b43102a31ce9180a4ea1f006f6675?query=map%28del%28.note%2C%20.age%29%29%20%7C%0Amap%28%20%0A%09if%20.phenotypes%20then%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%09%28.phenotypes%20%7C%3D%20map%28del%28.person_id%29%29%29%0A%09else%0A%09%09.%0A%09end%20%0A%29)

Comment: I think when I tried to use `if`, I hadn't realised that `else` was required.

Comment: I was trying to solve it using `.phenotypes?` but couldn't get it to stick. This way probably isn't that elegant, but there's always multiple ways of solving this stuff.

Comment: I saw other answers which suggested something similar, but I couldn't make that work either. I also tried ` // []` to get around the null issue, but it didn't like that either.